# Install python package through anaconda prompt using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, prompt, anaconda3

I tried to install `copy` package in spyder 3.8, using pip in the anaconda prompt. I wrote:

```
pip install pycopy-copy
```

I took it from [pycopy-copy.PyPl](https://pypi.org/project/pycopy-copy/)

However, I got an error:

```
(base) C:\Users\User>pip install pycopy-copy
Collecting pycopy-copy
  Downloading pycopy-copy-3.3.3.post7.tar.gz (3.7 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\User\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4ke9xgo0\\pycopy-copy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4ke9xgo0\\pycopy-copy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-me6bs5gs'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4ke9xgo0\pycopy-copy\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4ke9xgo0\\pycopy-copy\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Beyond the first 3 lines, every line is in red letters. I don't understand this error. And I have been getting this error with some other packages as well.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you updated setuptools? pip install -U setuptools

Comment: Do you really use [Pycopy](https://pycopy.github.io/)? If not you shouldn't use `pycopy` libraries including `pycopy-copy`. What problem are you trying to solve with `pycopy-copy`? Can you just use [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) from the standard library?

Comment: @phd Thank you, I wasn't aware that it was a built-in function. Some references such as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/ indicate that I should import the copy package.

Comment: @SaraIsabelAleixoPerestrelo Import — yes, install — no. Not a builtin, just a module from the standard library.